# How to remove light shadow-like color from an image

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I'm using opencv to process some images. I have a lot of images like below. They have some very light, shadow-like color.

What is the dimension that determine the color of the pixel is very light? What color space should I use to identify those light color pixels?

[image]

Comment: http://www.di.ubi.pt/~hugomcp/visaoComp/docs/Shadow_removal_5.pdf

Comment: Have you tried looking at [HSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV)? You can also try playing with the parameters of Lab/Luv color spaces. Additionally, if you have a lot of images with different colors, hence different shadows, you can train an SVN/neural network to bring all the shadows either to white (255, 255, 255) or the color next to it.

Comment: Those light areas are there for antialiasing. Why do you want to remove them ?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fairly simple method:

```
img = cv2.imread('4.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

img[gray > 200] = 255
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @RickM there are various color spaces available to analyze your image. Since you are focused on removing the shade/shadow you need to focus on channels that contain brightness information and keep the color channels aside.

In this case the LAB color space turned out to be helpful. The luminance channel expressed a lot of info on the amount of brightness in the image

```
img = cv2.imread('4.png')
lab = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab)

cv2.imshow('Luminance', l)
```

[image]

Then I obtained a threshold and masked the result with the original image to get `mask1`:

```
ret2, th = cv2.threshold(l, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV+cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
mask1 = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = th)
cv2.imshow('mask1', mask1)
```

[image]

But now the background is not what you intended it to be.
I created an image with white pixels of the same image dimension (`white`) and masked the inverted threshold image with it to get `mask2`:

```
white = np.zeros_like(img)
white = cv2.bitwise_not(white)

mask2 = cv2.bitwise_and(white, white, mask = cv2.bitwise_not(th))
cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
```

[image]

Upon adding both these images you get he intended image:

```
cv2.imshow('fin_img', mask2 + mask1)
```

[image]

Keep in mind that this would work only for similar images provided in the question.

Comment: As you mentioned, this would work only for the images (or similar) provided in the question. If the dataset has a lot of variation, using ML would be the best bet.

Comment: @RickM. The OP has mentioned *'I have a lot of images like below'*, I agree if this method is used for images with a dark background it would fail. Using ML wouldn't you have to provide a mask?

Comment: Not necessarily, you could do a color collection by looking at the color around the shadow and bring it to the required value (white or what the OP wants)